# CS50 Mario Question: Program collects input then does nothing

Tags: c, loops, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)

    {

        int height = 0;
        while(height < 1 || height > 8) {
            height = get_int("Height: ");
        }


        for(int spaces=height-1;spaces>0;spaces--) {

            for(int i=0; i==spaces; i++) {
                printf(" ");
            }

            for(int j=height-spaces;j==0;j--) {
                printf("#");

            }

            printf(" ");
            printf(" ");

            for(int k=height-spaces;k==0;k--) {
                printf("#");
            }


        }

    }
```

Obviously there is either an issue with my loops or I am using printf incorrectly.
I'm not understanding what is wrong with it. When I run the program it will get the input for variable height, then not print anything, returning to an empty command line.

Comment: `spaces` won't be zero, so `i==spaces` will never be true. Also `height-spaces` will never be zero, so `j==0` and `k==0` will also never be true. Replace the loop conditions to proper things according to what you want your program to do.

Comment: Currently `i` is not incremented because the loop is not executed because the condition is initially false.

Comment: Thank you Mike you were right. For some reason I thought it would run until they were equal to 0. Silly of me. Thanks